# Allowing Attributes in SoapVar / SoapHeader Without a Type Definition or Namespace

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I've been given a WSDL which does not contain any soap header schema or definitions, but the endpoint expects a WSSE-type header. I'm using `SoapClient` to handle these requests.

All requests must contain this in their header:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

If I go down the route suggested multiple times across StackOverflow and the online PHP documentation comments, the closest I can get is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="..." xmlns:ns2="..." xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns3:Security>
            <ns3:UsernameToken>
                <ns3:Username>Username</ns3:Username>
                <ns3:Password>Password</ns3:Password>
            </ns3:UsernameToken>
        </ns3:Security>
 ...
```

Notice how it adds the namespace to the soap envelope, while the spec / example given adds the namespace specifically to the `Security` element. I don't think this matters however. Either way, the Password element is missing it's type attribute.
I've also tried going down the array route, using:

```
$securityNamespace = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

// ...

$password = new \SoapVar(
    [
        '_' => 'Password',
        'type' => 'http://...'
    ],
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
    null,
    $securityNamespace,
    null,
    $securityNamespace
);
```

Which generates as:

```
<value>
    <item>
        <key>_</key>
        <value>PASSWORD</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>type</key>
        <value>http://...</value>
    </item>
</value>
```

Which is apparently a typical response when SoapClient can't find an element type to validate against.

The WSDL and accompanying XSDs are saved locally for caching purposes, would it be worth trying to modify the WSDL to include the WSSE header (if that's possible), or is there another logical way to generate the correct SOAP header for this namespace / XSD schema?

Comment: As a bit of flavor, the endpoint explicitly states why they do not include the header information in their WSDL: 1) That it's optional and 2) That it's best practice to not define authentication in order to keep it abstracted from the actual service.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/goetas-webservices/soap-client is fully PHP SOAP client that does not rely on the `ext-soap` from PHP.

It already supports is PSR7, multiclient and allows to have generated classes for type-hinting via your IDE.

https://github.com/goetas-webservices/soap-client-demo is demo project that allows you to see how to use the client to consume a generic SOAP webservice.